# I am creating database for checkbox with different column. How to insert the values to db?

Tags: php

I am creating database for checkbox values with different column. How to insert the db?because I have stored the check box values in different column name,my column name is allsubject,science,maths.

```
my questions are:
1.if user checks allsubject,the value is inserted, the other two column is going with null values. 
2.is this way of storing value is correct because among three check box user select any values, I want to clarify this?
3.More over I want to store the values  in this manner only
```

dbstructure:

```
**allsubject    science     maths**
   allsubject   science     maths
   allsubject   science     
                            maths
   allsubject  
Myform:
<form name="f1"  action="" method="post">
Student Name:<input type="text" name="sname" value=""/>
All Subject:<input type="checkbox" name="allsubject" value="allsubject"/>
Science<input type="checkbox" name="science" value="science"/>
Maths<input type="checkbox" name="maths" value="maths"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

**myphp value is:**
    <?php
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('checkbox');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='submit')
    {
    $allsubject=$_POST['allsubject'];
    $science=$_POST['science'];
    $maths=$_POST['maths'];
    $sql=mysql_query("insert into studentinfo (allsubject,science,maths) values ('".$allsubject."','".$science."','".$maths."')");
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['allsubject']){$allsubject=1;}  (OR VALUE YOU WANT)
```

Comment: I have done like this if(isset($_POST['allsubject']))
{
 $allsubject=$_POST['allsubject'];
}  
else
{
 $allsubject='null';
}
IF I fetch from sql ? who are using allsubject the null values is coming how to avoid that form db.

Comment: excuse me i don't understand what you want to avoid in db?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `studentinfo`  here I am sending null string which doesnot contain values .so If i want to list the table values it contains null string.how to avoid that one?

Comment: $sql=mysql_query("select * from studentinfo");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>
<p><?php echo $row['allsubject'];?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['science'];?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['maths'];?></p>
<?php
}
?>

Comment: Ok if you want to avoid completely a row select * from studentinfo where allsubject !='' but in the part of processing post checked or not checked values you have to change: $allsubject=''; then  if(isset($_POST['allsubject'])) { $allsubject=$_POST['allsubject']; }

Comment: Sorry I did not get you

Comment: if you want to avoid only the echo of value null <?php if($row['allsubject'] !=''){echo $row['allsubject'];}?>